# Directory selection screen, initial directory, standard directory in unattended mode

Tags: java, install4j

I have an installer that is using a **Directory selection** screen. The properties `initial directory` and `standard directory` are set to build a custom dir (like `c:\test` as `initial directory` and `myproduct\subdir` as `standard directory`).

Using the installer in GUI mode gives the desired result, the `initial directory` plus the `standard directory` together form the value for the variable of this screen (the variable is set to `c:\test\myproduct\subdir`).

In unattended mode, only the `initial directory` is used, but the `standard directory` is not appended, so the variable is set to `c:\test` only.

I think that the `handleUnattended()` method of `CustomizableDirectoryScreen` only takes the `getInitialDirectory()` but it does not use the `getStandardDirectoryName()`.

Is there a good way to have a working solution for all installer modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug and will be fixed in 6.1.2. please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is fixed.